# Restructure/Group data from an array of objects to be an array of arrays involving concatenation

Tags: php, arrays, object, concatenation, grouping

I am getting the array output from a query and I want to restructure it so that I can loop through the array and display it later. The array I am getting is:

```
$array = [
    (object) [
        'industry_name' => 'ABC Industry',
        'oil_grease_value' => 21.5,
    ],
    (object) [
        'industry_name' => 'XYZ Industry',
        'ph_value' => 9.10,
    ],
    (object) [
        'industry_name' => 'XYZ Industry',
        'total_suspended_solids' => 600.1,
    ],    
];
```

Now I want to restructure the array to something like this:

```
[
    [
        'industry_name' => 'ABC Industry',
        'parameter_name' => 'oil_grease_value',
    ],
    [
        'industry_name' => 'XYZ Industry',
        'parameter_name' => ', total_suspended_solids',
    ],
]
```

Comment: Do you have any attempt to show us? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Writing code fir you (because this isvwhat you ask for) is not considered helping here. Try yourself first, post your current code - then we will help.

Comment: Actually this output that i am getting is being generated after using three queries. So I have to display which industries are having parameters which exceeds certain value.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: I can post the whole code but in the end it will turn large...

Comment: Don’t post the _whole_ code, post the _relevant_ code.

Comment: The Code has been provided...

Comment: Which object in your code contains the array? I see your queries to fetch the data but no code for mapping it to the desired structure.

Comment: @dbrumann: I am not able to get my head around to the same. For that reason i am unable to restructure... I want help for that part only...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Everyone for the trouble. Found the Answer. Posted below if anybody requires in future:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  foreach($array[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        $industryArray[$key] = $value;
  }
}
print_r($industryArray);
```

Comment: This answer clearly does not provide the desired result from the sample data. https://3v4l.org/pXrc6

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an array of objects, plucking the last key from each object requires a little more work.

I recommend pushing reference variables into the result array to avoid calling `array_values()` after looping to remove the grouping keys.

When a given grouping key is encountered for the first time push the two elements as a reference row into the result array.  When encountered subsequent times, append a comma, space, and new value to the element in the reference row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/j1XaD))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    $key = $obj->industry_name;
    $param = array_key_last((array) $obj);
    if (!isset($ref[$key])) {
        $ref[$key] = [
            'industry_name' => $key,
            'parameter_name' => $param,
        ];
        $result[] = &$ref[$key];
    } else {
        $ref[$key]['parameter_name'] .= ", $param";
    }
}
var_export($result);
```